# Class list in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I don't know why, probably a simple answer, but I cant get this to work:

```
var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
if (classList.contains('closebutton') == true) {
    myActions();
}
```

Firebug tells me: TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined

Comment: does the element has a class attribute

Comment: Why not just write `if ($(this).hasClass("closebutton"))` ??

Comment: you can do the same with `this.className.split(/\s+/);`

Comment: What does $(this) evaluate as? Is it defined at that point?

Comment: you can use hasClass function. i.e $(this).hasClass('closebutton')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method instead:

```
if($(this).hasClass('class')) {
    myActions();
}
```

Comment: Definitely the way to handle this!

Comment: Actually didn't work either. Did a work around and solved it. Though this should be the proper solution, so I accept your answer.